# Is there any wsadmin command or query available to list all scopes while creating new JMS providers

Tags: jms, websphere, jython, wsadmin

For automation purpose i need to list all available scope present in the dropdown at the page of creating a new JMS providers.

My question is

1. Is there any command or query available for listing all available scope

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should help (depending on your next couple lines of code you might do a variant of this, but hoepfully it still helps):

```
CELL_NAME = AdminConfig.showAttribute(AdminConfig.list("Cell"), "name")

scopes = ["Cell", "Node", "Server", "ServerCluster"]

scopeList =[]
for scope in scopes:
    scopeList = scopeList + AdminConfig.list(scope, AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' +CELL_NAME)).split('\r\n')
```

Another shortcut of use might be to take something like the built in MQ provider which is available on all scopes and query that:

```
CELL_NAME = AdminConfig.showAttribute(AdminConfig.list("Cell"), "name")

print AdminConfig.list("JMSProvider", AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' +CELL_NAME))
```